# Can I use a power bank to power my laptop during a blackout?

Tags: battery-charging, power-consumption, laptop, backup, powerbanks

I am wondering if it's possible to use my ThinkPad L430 laptop with a power bank as a power source during a blackout. The laptop's power consumption is between ~35 to ~42 watts. Its battery is always charged but lasts only for an hour and a half as its capacity is at 33%.

I have a power bank that outputs 5V at either 2A or 1A, with a capacity of 10Ah. Can I use this power bank to power my laptop during a blackout?  If so, what would be the best way to go about it? How long it would last?

Comment: What voltage does the laptop require? I seriously doubt it is 5V. So you would need a converter. Then express both the power available (power bank) and power required (laptop) in the same units and see how long the powerbank will last - not long at a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Generally no. However newer notebook computers with USB-C PD chargers and a power bank with USB-C PD capability (ones that **include** capability to output the voltage the notebook requires) will work.

USB-C PD allows up to 100W power delivery (5A at 20V). Some USB-C PD power banks can support only up to 12V. For example, an current iPad pro USB-C charger supplies 9V at 2.2A or 5V at 3A. My nice Huawei 20Ah power bank can supply 5V/9V at 2A.

USB devices are supposed to negotiate to determine the correct voltage so it *shouldn't* hurt anything to try.

Comment: I can confirm that a T430 uses USB-C PD at 20V

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is no. 2 amps at 5V is 10 watts. Compare that to the laptop's power consumption; you state is between ~35 to ~42 watts. It will be a few watts short and probably not the correct voltage.